# I can’t open the Angular component page no matter what I do

Tags: node.js, angular

I tried everything to open the component page in Angular. However, only the main page always opens, which says "Congratulations! Your app is running", which is "app.component.html" file. How do I open "player-drag-drop.component.html" on the http://localhost:4200/ page?

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PlayerDragDropComponent } from './player-drag-drop/player-drag-drop.component';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ... other components
    PlayerDragDropComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // ... other modules
    DragDropModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [PlayerDragDropComponent]
})

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PlayerDragDropComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

player-drag-drop.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="players-list" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="onPlayerDropped($event)">
      <div *ngFor="let player of players" cdkDrag>{{ player.name }}</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="field" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="onFieldDropped($event)">
      <div *ngFor="let position of fieldPositions" cdkDrag>{{ getFieldPlayer(position) }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

player-drag-drop.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-player-drag-drop',
  templateUrl: './player-drag-drop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player-drag-drop.component.css']
})
export class PlayerDragDropComponent {
  players = [
    { name: 'Player 1', position: '' },
    { name: 'Player 2', position: '' },
  ];

  fieldPositions = ['Position 1', 'Position 2', 'Position 3', 'Position 4', 'Position 5'];

  onPlayerDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>): void {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

  onFieldDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>): void {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

  getFieldPlayer(position: string): string {
    const player = this.players.find(p => p.position === position);
    return player ? player.name : '';
  }
}
```

Would be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside AppModule: `RouterModule.forRoot({route: 'pageroute', component: YourComponent })`
2. Inside app.component.html: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

... more: https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt5

Answer (score 0):

In side your app.component.html - before the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is the original scaffolding.  If you delete that, your application will work as you have designed.  If you're using the angular router then you will have to configure the angular router.

[Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/routing-overview)